# MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'request' is not present

Tags: json, ajax, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I have a class with spring mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifier") 
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<String> adresseVoie(@RequestParam("request") String jsRequest) { 
    Verifier verifier = gson.fromJson(jsRequest, Verifier.class);  
}
```

In my ajax, i call the web service

```
var request = "request"+":{\"codePostal\":75010,\"lieuDit\":\"Paris\"}";

 $.ajax({
     url : 'http://localhost:8080/xxx/verifier',
     type : 'GET',
     dataType : 'json',
     data : JSON.stringify(request),
     success : function(code_retour, statut){ 
     },
     error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
     }
 });
```

Then i have the error

```
MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'request' is not present
```

Would you have an idea ?

Thanks

Thanks for your responses,
My file Java is now

> private Verifier verifier;
>
> @RequestMapping(value = "/verifier")  @ResponseBody  public
>   ResponseEntity adresseVoie(@RequestBody Verifier verifier) {

In my file javascript the data is

> data:"{codePostal:\""+codePostal+"\",lieuDit:\""+lieuDit+"\",pointGeographique:\""+pointGeographique+"\",pointRemise:\""+pointRemise+"\",ville:\""+ville+"\",voie:\""+voie+"\"}",

I have the error

> HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON:
>   No content to map to Object due to end of input; nested exception is
>   java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

I think my json is not good...
Do you see an error ?

Comment: You are sending a json body not a request parameter.

Comment: Hello M. Deinum, thanks for your response. an Object Java is constructed after recuperation in the webservice. The function in the WebService gson.fromJson({\"codePostal\":75010,\"lieuDit\":\"Paris\"}";Verifier.class);  give a good result but i don't know how to pass this in parameter...

Comment: You don't... Just add `@RequestBody Verifier verifier` to your method signature. Spring will do the marshaling for you. You are making things overly complex.

Comment: Can you post the query string when you do that request? and stack trace?